# Create new mail message with Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

When using the MS Graph API to POST a Mail message, the message is created in DRAFT mode.    Is there any way to create a new regular mail message which is not in DRAFT?
In addition, is there any option to POST a new message using MIME format in the body?

Answer (score 1):

When you create the Message you need to set the MessageFlags extended property to make it appear as if it was a Sent Message. You generally also want to set the ClientSubmitTime https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagclientsubmittime-canonical-property and the delivery time https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagmessagedeliverytime-canonical-property which affect how the messages will sort in Outlook. For MIME its export only in Beta at the moment https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/mime-format-support-for-microsoft-graph-apis-preview/

```
{
"Subject": "test1234",
"Sender": {
    "EmailAddress": {
        "Name": "blah",
        "Address": "blah@blah.com"
    }
},
"Body": {
    "ContentType": "HTML",
    "Content": "123Body"
},
"SingleValueExtendedProperties": [
    {
        "PropertyId": "Integer 0x0E07",
        "Value": "1"
    },
    {
        "PropertyId": "SystemTime 0x0039",
        "Value": "2019-06-12T10:10:47.2048+10:00"
    },
    {
        "PropertyId": "SystemTime 0x0E06",
        "Value": "2019-06-12T10:10:47.2048+10:00"
    }
]
}
```